# Having problems with pip install in WSL

Tags: python, pip, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hello I am trying to install `cysignals` to a conda environment (miniconda3) on  Windows10 pro.

But I keep getting this error:

```
(venv) C:\Users\ezgie\albatrosscraper>pip install cysignals
Collecting cysignals
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/5f/727aa099de5c60b3fb42cdde72097277803dabe78b177afdb5b835bbf909/cysignals-1.10.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Cython>=0.28 in c:\users\gie\.conda\envs\scraper\lib\site-packages (from cysignals) (0.29.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: cysignals
  Building wheel for cysignals (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Users\gie\.conda\envs\scraper\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ezgie\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a3z1c01o\\cysignals\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\gie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-y7d4uyav' --python-tag cp36:
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
  running build
  error: [WinError 2] system cannot find the file specified
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cysignals
  Running setup.py clean for cysignals
Failed to build cysignals
Installing collected packages: cysignals
  Running setup.py install for cysignals ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Users\gie\.conda\envs\scraper\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\gie\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a3z1c01o\\cysignals\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\gie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-767tzgab\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    error: [WinError 2] system cannot find the file specified
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'C:\Users\gie\.conda\envs\scraper\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\gie\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a3z1c01o\\cysignals\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\gie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-767tzgab\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\gie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a3z1c01o\cysignals\
```

I also tried to install it to WSL using `pip install` but then I got this error:

```
eri@DESKTOP-LGHM:~$ pip install cysignals
Collecting cysignals
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 630, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 190, in resolve_redirects
    **adapter_kwargs
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 643, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 315, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'`
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

So for the WSL the problem was Windows Firewall. I added wsl.exe to exceptions and problem is solved